# can someone help me fix this issue with my code relating main methods and files

Tags: java

I am having trouble with my general java code to run. the main method and file is the error messages im receiving.

I tried to change my code however it kept getting worse.

My current code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Submission {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
            public static void name () {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("tall.txt"));
            int[] tall = new int[100];
            int i = 0;
            while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                tall[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "this is the code" can you read it in the comment? Because I can't, and I doubt many others will be able to either. [Edit] your question and add the code there.

Comment: And from a really quick glance you defined a method inside your `main` method, which you can't do.

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: I edited your question to add your code there since as new member of this site you may not be familiar with editing yet. But to get better experience here and better chances of getting proper answer consider reading our [help] to learn how to post proper questions. You may also be interested in [Community FAQ for all Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931) and 
[Community FAQ for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251225)

Answer (score 0):

1. You have one static method inside of another. This does not work.
2. Using Scanner can throw a checked exception so you have to declare it in the method signature.

Taking this into account, this at least compiles:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Submission {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("tall.txt"));
      int[] tall = new int[100];
      int i = 0;
      while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        tall[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't have a method inside a another method. Try this code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(newFile("tall.txt"));
        int[] tall = new int[100];
        int i = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            tall[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
}
}
}
```